# Selling digital tickets who owns the data?

Tags: internet, ownership, digital-contract

If I sell digital tickets in the UK using an online platform, and they provide the means for me to download that data, who owns that data? Is it the person who paid for the ticket, the platform or me the event organiser?

Comment: By "the data", do you mean a list like "Joe Doe bought one ticket for concert X, Jane Doe bought one ticket for concert Y etc."?

Comment: The data contains the name and email of the ticket holder, ticket tier information as well as the barcode to identify the ticket